# Search Windows 10 directory for subfolders and files with common words in their names without specifying the words

Tags: windows-10, powershell, search, duplicate

Hard to explain! Please bear with me...

1. I rip my vinyl record collection to MP3 format. Each album gets its own folder. The naming standard I use for each album folder is "Artist - Album".
2. I compress the larger folders to zip files but leave the smaller ones as is.
3. Now the tricky part: I decide to move artists with more than 1 album into a separate parent folder. Is there a way to automate the search for multiple instances of the same artist name among the folders and zip files in a single sweep?

For example, if 1000 artists feature on only 1 album each in my collection, and another 300 artists appear on 2 albums each, is there a way for me to run a search that picks up the latter 600 albums (which will be a mix of folders and zip files) based on partial duplication of file names? Variations of alphabetical sorting, or having to include any part of 300 artist names, won't get the job done.

**Question:** Anyone out there feel like helping me understand better how I could get any level of assistance or guidance for this?

I'm not opposed to using a 3rd party tool, command line, or a PowerShell script ultimately if I can get my head around it.

My scripting skills are disastrous enough to potentially end life on Earth, so I feel like I need to stay in my lane but wanted to see what advice or guidance SuperUser community can give me otherwise.

---

[Thank you for the comments and tips, and thank you also to whoever tidied up my original draft. Apologies for my 3am caveman missteps. To Vomit IT: Build a man a fire and he'll be warm for a night, but set him on fire and he'll be warm for the rest of his life! Cheers, Boss.]

Comment: Hello. Yes, you need a script. But also this is not a free scripting website. It's Q&A where you need to ask an accurate question, if you e.g. encounter problems while creating a script yourself.

Comment: As a starting point, find a list of recording artists online. Then write a script that searches the directory tree for file names matching an artist. Consider that it might take some time: if you have 10,000 albums, and are matching against 1,000 names, that's 10,000,000 comparisons. Also remember to mach only files, not folders.

Comment: You do not need scripting services, you just need to try some PS commands and show what you try and is not working. Your explanation is good for your requirements though.  Google `Get-ChildItem` using recursive commands and then pipe those over to `| ForEach-Object { If($_ -match "artistPicaso") {$_}}` and get your desired output. You might have to slip in some `-splits "-"` to make arrays, massage, etc. but google those things, try to get output desired, and wrapping commands around those is easy. You just need some commands, not a script. Then [Edit] and show what you need help with further.

Comment: One other starting point other than googling for some examples right to the point for what they do, etc. check out these posts for helping you find something close enough and relevant enough for you to adjust accordingly to accommodate your needs
: https://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a510662%20Body%3aget-childitem&searchOn=3. Good Luck!!

Comment: You just gotta try some things to learn to satisfy the way it operates around here, just show whatever code you are trying and having trouble with. If you must have a legit  good effort on your part question for each command to make some ultimate script, then so be it, do it one command at a time, and one question at a time and learn while you go. Try it, it is really fun, and you will be surprised how quick once you do it over and over, how much easier it gets with each repitition.